# A way to store /home/$USER for testing

Tags: shell

I'm new to shellscript, I don't want the user to have to type the full path to a directory when running the program.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Tests the directory, if there is a return
#XXX I want to prevent the user from entering 
# the entire path /home/$USER

echo "Enter search directory: "
read dir

if test -d  "$dir"
then
    echo "Found directory: $dir"
else
    echo "Directory not found!"
fi
```

Execution example:

```
> ./dir
>> Enter the directory: 
>>> /home/$USER/Downloads
>>>> Directory Found: /home/user/Downloads
```

What I want:

```
> ./dir
>> Enter the directory:
>>> Downloads
>>>> Directory Found: /home/user/Downloads
```

Comment: Good job including some code in your very first question!(Q) BUT ... we (I) don't know what you mean by *omit a passage to be typed*. Please edit your Q to show a sample use-case of your script. Are you saying there are 2 ways you want to use this? Do you want `./myScript mySpecialDir` vs just `./myScript` which would then prompt you `"Enter search directory:"`? Again, don't reply in comments, improve  your Q with a sample of how you want to use your script and why it's not working now. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I know I said not to comment, but as I managed to resolve it, I was not clear when asking my question. I wanted to store /home/$USER so the user wouldn't have to type. I achieved this using the variable dir:, dir = "/home /$USER/$dir.

Comment: you improved your Q, so comments are fine. Glad you found a solution! Keep posting! (I would recommend considering adding a variable like `base_dir=/home/$USER`, and append `$dir` to that. Otherwise you might wind up with `/home/$USER/Downloads/home/$USER/Downloads/.?.?...?`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented this, and it got better!